# How to avoid Google API Python Client warning about 3 positional arguments instead 2 required?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-api, google-api-python-client

I use [Google API Python Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/GoogleAppEngine) to work with another Google service and the following code to authorize there with Service account:

```
credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
service = build('fusiontables', 'v1', http=http)
```

Quite often I observe the following records in the application log:

```
I 2014-05-22 19:06:19.658
Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
W 2014-05-22 19:06:19.666
__init__() takes at most 2 positional arguments (3 given)
```

Is there any change in my code required to avoid this warning message?